# Woocommerce Custom Add to Cart URL

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a question with adding a product to the cart via a url. Right now I can use http://example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=49 and it will add the item to the cart. I'm using a plugin that adds a custom text input to each product. The plugin is WooCommerce Extra Product Options on codecanyon.

I need to add a parameter to my add to cart url where I can add an item to the cart but also pass a value to that custom input through the url as well. Ideally my url would look something like http://example.com/cart/?add-to-cart=49&textbox=myvalue. I'm really not sure the best way to approach this. I'm not against not using that plugin either if there is a better way to make this work. Thanks for your help.